# Retrieving a stored email attachment as a byte[] from Rabbit MQ doesn't send email

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, email-attachments

I'm convert an svg object to a byte[] and storing this in a queue with the following class

```
public class MailMessage
{  
    public string AttachmentName { get; set; }    
    public byte[] Attachment { get; set; }
}
```

However the email never gets sent. I'm thinking that the attachment is corrupt because if we skip adding the attachment to the email then it sends fine.

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(attachment))
{
  var mailMessage = new MailMessage(this.from, new MailAddress(recipient)) { Subject = subject, Body = message };

  // this is the line which if commented out allows the email to be sent 
  mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, filename));

  MailSender().SendAsync(mailMessage, null);
}
```

A co-worker suggested that the byte[] may have been compromised due to the way rabbit stores messages and to therefore base64 encode the byte[] before storing it using the built in functions

```
Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)

Convert.FromBase64String(message.Attachment) // to retrieve
```

However that didn't work either.

Can anyone think why this is failing to send and think of any work-arounds.

I'm contemplating storing the image in the database and deleting it once the email is sent, but this is a last resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is  with `MailSender.SendAsync()`. The `stream` object is get disposed before the mail is sent.

Don't use "`using`" here. You are destroying the memory stream immediately 
after calling `SendAsync`, e.g. probably before SMTP gets to read it 
(since it's async).

Either Destroy your stream in the callback.

or

Use `MailSender.Send()` instead of `MailSender.SendAsync()` to send synchronusly.

[Refer this for more detail](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/winforms/thread/477d9b5b-bc6e-4fe3-9734-820211ae250f)

Comment: That is so simple it's frustrating. Thank you for your help